# Setting up TXT records in dnsmasq does not work

Tags: debian, dns, dnsmasq, dig

I want to configure some TXT records in my local dnsmasq which runs on a singleboardcomputer and servers DHCP and DNS in my local network.

I use it to make my services that I selfhost at home reachable under the same FQDN as from the Internet, but with local IPv4 addresses in the A records.

That works fine.

However i'm struggling to get dnsmasq to resolve TXT records. After I tried around and could not get my desired records to resolve, I copied the example TXT record from the example.conf into my dnsmasq.conf

```
#Example zeroconf
txt-record=_http._tcp.example.com,name=value,paper=A4
```

reloaded dnsmasq and then tried

```
dig _http._tcp.example.com TXT @192.168.2.15
```

which yields an empty result.

dnsmasq.log says however:

```
Sep 29 21:59:07 dnsmasq[725]: query[TXT] _http._tcp.example.com from 192.168.2.111                                               
Sep 29 21:59:07 dnsmasq[725]: forwarded _http._tcp.example.com to 12.23.45.57
```

I tried to google this, but all i find is links to the example.conf or manual.

I read the manpage and the config file, but i could not find any config switch which seems to be mandatory for TXT records to be resolved locally. Has anybody succeeded?

Thanks!

Comment: so you are querying `TXT` for example.com ?

Comment: I'm querying the record that I have setup in dnsmasq before, I'd expect dnsmasq to realize it does not need to forward this query and instead answer what I configured.

Comment: You "literally copied" it?  It's a comment.  Did you _really_ literally copy a comment?  If you did not, then you must [edit] your question to correct say what you really did, which won't be "literally".

Comment: @JdeBP you're right. I did in fact not *literally* copy it, of course i had removed the "'#" in my config, but when i copy pasted it into my question here, i did not remove it. So i have updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I would have preferred to send a comment, but my reputation does not allow me to do so. But, as your question is `Has anybody succeeded?`, I suppose an answer with my own experience is fine here.

To be brief, yes, I have succeeded, doing exactly what you did :

**Server side (Raspbian "buster"):**

```
br@idril:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster

br@idril:~$ dnsmasq --version
Dnsmasq version 2.80  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 Simon Kelley
Compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
[...]

br@idril:~$ hostname -I
192.168.0.120

br@idril:~$ hostname -d
lan

br@idril:~$ grep ^txt /etc/dnsmasq.conf
txt-record=lan,"v=spf1 a -all"
txt-record=_http._tcp.lan,name=value,paper=A4

br@idril:~$ sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq.service
```

**Client side (Ubuntu "impish") :**

```
br@lorien:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    security-11.1.0ubuntu3-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish

br@lorien:~$ hostname -d
lan

br@lorien:~$ dig +short TXT _http._tcp.lan @192.168.0.120
"name=value" "paper=A4"

br@lorien:~$ dig +short TXT lan @192.168.0.120
"v=spf1 a -all"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had gone another route and not really followed up the attempt of using dnsmasq for this. But now as I try again, it suddenly indeed works. I still had the example configuration in my dnsmasq.conf and I can't imagine what i might have possibly done wrong when using dig. But it works now... funny. Maybe i have another application for this now :) thx for reminding me!